# Copying range to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets: DATA, BUILD and RESULT.
DATA - contains all data
BUILD - 1 row that is iterated through VBA procedure (below) and a command button.
RESULT - where I need to put every iterated row of BUILD table.

The following part of the code is expected to add new row to a RESULTS table.
In a RESULTS sheet, rows are copied sometimes in row 2567, sometimes in 237 etc.
I can't understand the logic how VBA determines the row it puts copied rows.

```
Sheets("RESULTS").Range("A2" & i + 1).Value = Sheets("BUILD").Range("D4").Value 'League Name
Sheets("RESULTS").Range("B2" & i + 1).Value = Sheets("BUILD").Range("E4").Value 'Home Team
Sheets("RESULTS").Range("C2" & i + 1).Value = Sheets("BUILD").Range("F4").Value 'Away Team
```

This is the full code:

```vb
Sub btn_NextMatch()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Volatile
    Dim Last_row As Double
    Dim Last_Col As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sheet As String
    sheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    Sheets("BUILD").Select
    i = Range("A1").Value
     
    Sheets("DATA").Select
    Last_row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Last_Col = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
    Last_colletter = Split(Cells(1, Last_Col).Address, "$")(1)
    If i = Last_row Then
        i = 1
    End If
    
    Sheets("BUILD").Range("C2").Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("C" & i + 1).Value 'MatchID
            
    Sheets("BUILD").Range("D4").Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("D" & i + 1).Value 'League Name
    Sheets("BUILD").Range("E4").Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("F" & i + 1).Value 'Home Team
    Sheets("BUILD").Range("F4").Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("G" & i + 1).Value 'Away Team
    
    Sheets("BUILD").Select
    
    If i = Last_row Then
        Range("A1").Value = 1
    Else
        Range("A1").Value = i + 1
        Sheets("RESULTS").Range("A2" & i + 1).Value = Sheets("BUILD").Range("D4").Value 'League Name
        Sheets("RESULTS").Range("B2" & i + 1).Value = Sheets("BUILD").Range("E4").Value 'Home Team
        Sheets("RESULTS").Range("C2" & i + 1).Value = Sheets("BUILD").Range("F4").Value 'Away Team
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Sheets(sheet).Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There are a few ways to improve this code, most notably eliminating `Select` and `Activate`, although your problem appears to be adding the `Last_row` to `2` in each case.  If your last row = 25, you just made it row 225.  Remove the 2 after A, B and C.

Comment: In what sheet is `i`?

Comment: Thank you, @Darrell! Removing 2 after A, B and C did the trick and it works well! Can you please explain regarding improvement. I have tried removing `Select` but then it stops working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend using offset to counter the previous problem.  Here are a few items corrected in the code:

1. Declare last row, column, etc as `Long`.  There are over 1 million rows in Excel and integer will only handle up to 32,767.  After that you will overload the value.
2. Shorten the workbook names by setting them as variables.  No need to Dim as string.
3. Avoid `Select` and `Activate` by qualifying your worksheets and variables.  That means giving as full information as needed to specify the location `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` versus `Range("A1")` that could be any sheet.  Not only will this ensure proper locations, but will speed up your code by avoiding changing sheets.

   ```
    Sub btn_NextMatch()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Volatile
    Dim Last_row As Long
    Dim Last_Col As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Dim wks1 As Worksheet
    Dim wks2 As Worksheet
    Dim wks3 As Worksheet

    Set wks1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BUILD")
    Set wks2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
    Set wks3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RESULTS")

    i = wks1.Range("A1").Value

    Last_row = wks2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Last_Col = wks2.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
    Last_colletter = Split(wks2.Cells(1, Last_Col).Address, "$")(1)
    If i = Last_row Then
        i = 1
    End If

        wks1.Range("C2").Value = wks2.Range("C" & i + 1).Value 'MatchID
        wks1.Range("D4").Value = wks2.Range("D" & i + 1).Value 'League Name
        wks1.Range("E4").Value = wks2.Range("F" & i + 1).Value 'Home Team
        wks1.Range("F4").Value = wks2.Range("G" & i + 1).Value 'Away Team

    If i = Last_row Then
       wks1.Range("A1").Value = 1
    Else
        wks1.Range("A1").Value = i + 1
        wks3.Range("A" & i + 1).Value = wks1.Range("D4").Value 'League Name
        wks3.Range("B" & i + 1).Value = wks1.Range("E4").Value 'Home Team
        wks3.Range("C" & i + 1).Value = wks1.Range("F4").Value 'Away Team
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End sub
   ```

Comment: I try, but get the error 424 (Object Required) in this line:  Last_Col = wsk2.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Should have been wks2, not wsk2.

Answer (score 0):

Darrel H. is right. If you are concatenating the iteration you're on to the cell address you are doing equivalent of: "A2" & 25 becomes A225, where you really wanted to have "A27". A way around this is to use the offset function. Your code rewritten would be like this:

```
Sheets("RESULTS").Range("A2" & i + 1).offset(rowoffset:=i + 1).value = Sheets("BUILD").Range("D4").Value 'League Name'
```